# Django & Celery: How do I schedule a job to run only once using Celery(similar to "at" command in linux)?

Tags: django, celery, schedule

I looked at django-celery tutorial and I think it will really help me running the background tasks without letting the users to wait. However, I have a specific requirement in the program such that when user enters a date, django should be able to do the scheduling and defer the execution to a later time. I have used `at` program before but it gives a lot of permission issues. But when I read the documentation for Celery, I can only see that Celery supports `cron` like tasks called `@periodic_task`. I'm sure that it also provides `at` like mechanism, but I couldn't find any documentation. Can anybody point me to some resources or simply tell me how to achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The docs state that you can [schedule tasks to execute at a specific time](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#module-celery.task.base), using the [eta argument](http://ask.github.io/celery/userguide/executing.html#eta-and-countdown).

Comment: eta argument link is dead. [eta](http://ask.github.io/celery/userguide/executing.html#eta-and-countdown)

Answer (score 3):

You can supply the countdown or ETA argument to the apply_async() function. By doing so, you can define the earliest time that the task is gonna be executed, but not the exact one (it depends on your queue). For more details see [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html?highlight=eta#eta-and-countdown).

Comment: page doesn't exists